# without using x.insert( ) modify given list

Tags: python

I am currently really stuck on a question. I need to create a function that takes the list, the value to be inserted, and an insertion location as parameters and inserts the value at the insertion location. *without using `x.insert()` function*.

i understand that i have to  append each individual value in the list into a new list within the function with a for loop. And then if I = the place the user wants to insert the new one value. Append that one and return it into the list so that the new modified list can then be printed. I just cant seem to put it into my code...

Comment: Can you use [slicing](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html)?  Hint: `x[:index]` gives you everything up to an index,`x[index:]` gives you everything from an index on, and lists can be concatenated with the `+` operator.

Comment: yes i can use slicing

Comment: You can use list.insert(location, value) inbuilt function. No need to manually traverse the loop

Comment: @Optimus You clearly missed the emphasized part of the question indicating that the OP *could not use the x.insert() method*. Also, it's *in the title* of the question.

Comment: @CP_nate Then I would suggest taking what I've given you, open a Python console, and play around with it until you have crafted a solution.

Answer (score 1):

If part of the requirement is to modify the list *in-place* rather than to return a newly created list, then you can use slices as l-values:

```
def your_insert(list, newvalue, index):
    list[index:index] = [newvalue]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def your_insert(lst, newvalue, index):
     final_lst = []
     L1 = lst[index:]
     final_lst = lst[:index] + [newvalue] + L1
     return final_lst
```

Assumption: Indexing is starting from 0.

Comment: Why do you add one to `index` only to subtract it out again in the slices?

Comment: Make running time longer by a constant factor ;)